# Modify an R function to add extra output?

Tags: r, function, compilation

I would like the lineal model regression command "lm()" also added information about the confidence interval.

What file should I modidy to get it?

At worst I would need to recompile something, but I hope I could compile only a single file.

What should I do?

Another option would be to create a script that get launched at startup and overwrite the regular behaviour or lm.  How?

Comment: you could use `fixInNamespace("lm","stats")` but it is probably safer and more portable to write your own function adding whatever you want to lm's output and using `res_lm <- lm(model) res_lm <- myfunc(res_lm)`

Comment: if you just want to be able to see the confidence interval with the summary output then you can just override the `print.lm` function: `print.lm <- function(x, ...) { print(summary(x)) ; cat("Confidence interval:\n") ; print(confint(x)) }` ; otherwise you'll have to write a wrapper for `lm` that calls `stats::lm` and adds the `confint` data to the `list` structure but still preserve the `lm` class. If you don't just want the `print.lm` solution, @scoa's suggestion to not override `lm` and make your own function is the soundest and most portable approach.

Comment: OK, maybe overriding it it's a bad idea because other functions may be affected too.  @hrbrmsts idea sounds well. What's the best way to make it permanent? Have that new functions for future R sessions?.  Anyway I want to modify several R functions to mimic Sata's output because my boss like them.

Answer (score 3):

What you can use is something called a [function operator](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html). A function operator takes a function as input, adds a bit of functionality and returns a function.

For example, to create a version of `lm` that always reports the `summary`:

```
tweak_lm = function(modify_function) {
    function(...) {
        result = lm(...)
        print(modify_function(result))
        result
    }
}
summarized_lm = tweak_lm(summary)
lm_res = summarized_lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = ..1, data = ..2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.5432 -2.3647 -0.1252  1.4096  6.8727 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  37.2851     1.8776  19.858  < 2e-16 ***
wt           -5.3445     0.5591  -9.559 1.29e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.046 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7528,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7446 
F-statistic: 91.38 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 1.294e-10

> lm_res

Call:
lm(formula = ..1, data = ..2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt  
     37.285       -5.344  

>
```

Using this approach enables you to create other variants of this:

```
coef_lm = tweak_lm(coef)
lm_res = coef_lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

(Intercept)          wt 
  37.285126   -5.344472
```

It is not completely clear what you need, but you can use this approach.